# Finding parent collection by filtering collection of complex type using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class structure

```
public class Document
{
    [BsonId]
    public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private List<KeywordModel> _domain;

    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    public int FileSize { get; set; }

    public string DocumentType { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public string DateTime { get; set; }

    public List<KeywordModel> Domain {
        get { return this._domain; }
        set { this._domain = value;}
    }

    public Document()
    {

        this._domain = new List<KeywordModel>();

    }
}


public class KeywordModel
{
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of the parent Document class like: `List<Document>`. I want to write a LINQ query, which will take a `List<string>` and match with the property of the `KeywordModel.Keyword`. Further it returns the collection of `Document` from the `List<Document>`.

Answer (score 0):

All documents with at least 1 keyword match:

```
List<string> keywords = ...;
IEnumerable<Document> allDocuments = null;
var documents = allDocuments.Where(d => d.Domain.Any(kw => keywords.Contains(kw.Keyword))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

An non Linq approach:

You can use the FindAll-Methods of `List<T>`. For example:

```
List<string> matches = new List<string> {"test", "test2", "test3"};

documentList.FindAll(d => d.Domain.Exists(keyModel => matches.Contains(keyModel.KeyWord)));
```